# what is causing my new build to run slowly? or is being bottlenecked?

Tags: performance

I just built a new tower. Not the greatest, but-since I don't game, it's nice enough for me.

- antec 902
- asus M4A78LT-M board
- AMD 1065 6 core, (2.9)
- seasonic 520 modular
- corsair H60
- Corsair xms 4 x 4 gig ddr3 1333
- western digital 1 tb 7200 sata hd
- corsair 30 gig accelerator ssd
- lg dvd-rw sata, lg dvd-rom
- vantec 3.5 card reader
- pny gt430 pci-e video card.

The problem is -- it's slow !! I'm on comcast cable and just got a zoom 3.0 modem\gateway. It shows a ping of 50 and a download speed of 24-25, and a upload of a little over 3 mps. I'm only paying for 15 and 3 so that's ok.

I'd like to overclock but am clueless about it, and can't change the values in my boards bios. Any suggestions ??

What's the best free benchmark site to use that I can understand ?? It's gotta be bottlenecked somewhere !! Video card ?? Thanks for any help provided !! It seems that the experts don't feel that I asd a real question, but I felt I did !! I'm curious about the best benchmark sites (free) to provide me somewhere to start to improve the performance of it. The NovaBench provided a score of 929, which is low for the components used, but I feel that a video card upgrade is needed. Yet, since I don't game, I didn't feel that I needed more than I bought at the time. So ***experts*** is it a video card problem, and do you have 1 that you suggest ???

Comment: What exactly is it that's slow?

Comment: surfing in general

Comment: Is the browser lagging (e.g. not responding, pointer hangs etc), or is it just long wait-time to connect and download web-sites?

Answer (score 3):

You havent really provided any numbers, but assuming you are talking about gaming performance, you are being bottlenecked by your GPU

http://www.guru3d.com/article/geforce-gt-430-review/13

If you provide some more details: resolution, type of slowdown,etc it may be easier to highlight the issue

Also, your PC's hardware configuration has **NOTHING** to do with your internet speeds at those speeds

Comment: I don't game but it seems slow surfing wise considering the components used. Thats why I'd like to find a free benchmark program I can use and post the results so it's easier for people to offer advice\tips. I need to upgrade the video card I think, but the 1 I have has so many adjustments that I don't understand already. I use my flat panel tv as a monitor at 1280 x 720 and my 5.1 home theater for the audio. Himi out to the tv and optical to the receiver. It did improve when I installed the corsair ssd.